# Insert a Web Page into a Presentation

Tags: ms-office

On Windows, there is a PowerPoint plugin that allows live webpages to be inserted into a presentation.

I will be doing a presentation and it involves a web demo. I was wondering if a similar solution exists on the mac. It can be any presentation software, it just needs to have the ability to embed a live webpage and interact with that page.

<sup>I am using OS X Mavericks on a mid-2012 Macbook Air.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Keynote '08 has the ability to do this by selecting `Insert -> Web View`. Unfortunately, for some inexplicable reason, Keynote '09 omitted this feature. You can, however, create a presentation in the former, and use this object in the latter (or so I recall, as I no longer have Keynote '08 on which to test.)